# Xcode get error when using Coapod

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapod to get Global Lib. It works fine in the simulator, but it has some error when I build on my device:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IQRequest.o
  "_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey", referenced from:
      ___78-[IQRequest performQueueOperationWithRequest:withSuccessBlock:andFailedBlock:]_block_invoke39 in IQRequest.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IQRequest.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IQRequest.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ChooseDesignerViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in IQUser.o
      objc-class-ref in IQAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What has happened to my project?

Comment: Show your Podfile, please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your library isn't compiled for armv7s. If it's distributed as binary you'll have to ask the maintainer to rebuild it with an armv7s slice. If it's distributed as source code you have to check the projects build settings. I think you should look for valid architectures or something like that.